# Running mocha test suites in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, mocha.js

I am using mocha.js (v 3.4) to run end 2 end tests. Each end2end test case resides in a folder. For each test case, I run through the same base API tests. Those tests cases form the 'test suite'. So in summary I have:

Test case 1 - run through tests 1-5 in a particular suite

Test case 2 - run through same 1-5 tests in same the suite

Test case 3 - run through same 1-5 tests in the same suite

And so on.

The problem is that currently I take in each test case and run tests 1-5 before moving onto the next test case and so on, so each end2end test case is run in a sequential manner and it is taking time to run through all the 
tests. In pseudocode, it is something like this:

```
describe("..: e2e tests", function() {
    for (const testPath of casesPaths) {
        e2eTestSuite(testPath);
    }
});
```

Where 'testPath' is the path to the test case. As you can see, I'm looping through the test cases one by one, running the testSuite on each test case sequentially.

I would like to know how to parallelize this so that I can run multiple e2e tests at once. Is this possible, and, if so, can they be run using 'grunt'?

Comment: `mocha-parallel-tests` NPM Package might help you

Comment: @planet_hunter thank you. Do you mind elaborating on your answer a bit with a short usage example(I don't wan't to run individual tests in a suite in parallel, rather end2end tests(each e2e test consists of several tests as above) and how you might integrate it with grunt.

Comment: I did use that package in the end- and split my describes up into different files. It isn't possible as yet to integrate it with grunt so used npm test